# iframe returns content using the server internet connection

Tags: c#

Does anyone know if it is possible to code an iframe on a website to return data using the servers internet connection as opposed to the clients?

Thanks

Comment: You need to be much clearer in Your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
Call the url in your code, then pass the html from the response to be rendered in the iFrame.